# How to override a type member adding more mixins to it

Tags: scala, traits

It's easier to explain by example. I have a `Base` trait which defines type `Rec`:

```
trait A
trait B
trait C

trait Base {
  type Rec <: A
  def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ???
}
```

Now I want to create 'enrichers' for `Base` which add some functionality using abstract override modifier on overrode methods and at the same time make type `Rec` more concrete (depending on task concrete enricher performs):

```
trait Enricher1 extends Base {
  override type Rec <: Base#Rec with B
  abstract override def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ??? // uses super.foo
}

trait Enricher2 extends Base {
  override type Rec <: Base#Rec with C
  abstract override def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ??? // uses super.foo
}
```

The problem is: I can't mix my enrichers together:

```
trait Concrete extends Base
trait Custom extends Concrete with Enricher1 with Enricher2
```

Compiler rejects this saying basically that type `Rec` in `Enricher1` and `Rec` in `Enricher2` are incompatible, and I highly agree with him. Note that it does compile with single enricher.

So, instead of writing

```
override type Rec <: Base#Rec with B
```

I would rather say: give me the same type as Rec already is but add `with X` to it. I tried

```
override type Rec <: super.Rec with B
```

but it's rejected by compiler too with 'cyclic aliasing' error.

How can I do that?

Comment: Agreeing with the compiler: always a good thing to do :)

Comment: Have you tried removing `override` before the `type`? Let it be simply `type Rec <: C`. It should allow you to mix all traits.

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev, no, it won't compile. The goal is to add new 'with X' with every mixed-in trait layer.

Comment: @Tvaroh, I had something similar in `frames` (https://github.com/Primetalk/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/frames.scala). In base trait the type is "abstract", unconstrained. Then I can have a few descendant traits that applies some constraints. And that frames can be mixed together freely. To call ancestor method, you can have to use "self" specialization (`trait Desc {self <: Ancestor => ...}`)

Comment: @ArseniyZhizhelev, you can't call ancestor (super) method with self types. `self.foo` is just foo, not `super.foo`. It's only possible with abstract override.

Comment: Looks like I need sort of `abstract override` for types and it's not possible in Scala. Perhaps, I should rethink my design.

Comment: You can try to use aggregation instead of inheritance. When you aggregate your "ancestor" you can freely call it's methods. And you can use it's types. And you can construct a type based on the "ancestor's" type. See in `frames` the usage of `type AllSlots`. It's the type constructed from other instances.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand what you are trying to do, this is what I think can be done:

```
trait A
trait B
trait C

trait Base {
  type Rec <: A
   def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ???
}

trait Enricher1 extends Base {
  override type Rec <: Base#Rec with C
   abstract override def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ??? // uses super.foo
}
trait Enricher2 extends Enricher1 {
  override type Rec <: Enricher1#Rec with B
  abstract override def foo(r: Rec): Rec = ??? // uses super.foo
}
trait Concrete extends Base
trait Custom extends Concrete with Enricher2
```